# Struggling to solve this Cal II integral: $∫ \frac{3t^{1/2}}{1+t^{1/3}}\text dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral for homework in a Cal II class. I feel I've tried everything. What am I missing?

Again, here is the integral:
$$∫ \frac{3t^{1/2}}{1+t^{1/3}} \text dt$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please tell us a bit of what you have tried. Also, please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your question, since it will increase readability (and thus the willing to put some effort in answering).

Comment: Take .$u^6=t$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As lcm$(2,3)=6,$ set $t^{1/6}=y\implies t^{1/2}=y^3,t^{1/3}=y^2$ and $t=y^6,dt=6y^5dy$

$$\int\dfrac{3t^{1/2}}{1+t^{1/3}}dt=\int\dfrac{3y^3}{1+y^2}6y^5dy$$

$$=18\int\dfrac{y^8-1+1}{y^2+1}dy$$

$$=18\int(y^6-y^4+y^2-1)dy+18\dfrac{dy}{1+y^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $u = t^6$.Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Set $u=\sqrt[6] t$ and $du=\frac{dt}{6t^{5/6}}$

$$18\int \frac{u^8}{u^2+1}du$$

Now do long division

$$18\int(u^6-u^4+u^2+\frac{1}{u^2+1}-1)du=\dots\\=\frac{18u^{7}}{7}-\frac{18u^5}{5}+6u^3-18u+18\arctan u +\mathcal C=\dots$$

Comment: Thank you. They hadn't taught backwards substitution yet (often this happens), and so I hadn't considered this method. Helped a lot, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The hint $t=y^6$ having been given already, you are let with $$I=18\int\dfrac{y^8}{y^2+1}dy$$ Now, perform the long division $$\dfrac{y^8}{y^2+1}=y^6-y^4+y^2-1+\frac{1}{y^2+1}$$ and the problem becomes simple.